# MoveIt self-filtering

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!I want to use MoveIt to do robot planning&executation, so I use a Kinect to sensor the surrounding world. The tf tree is divided into two parts, robot and the Kinect connecting by world link. I have added the self mask in the YAML file, but there're no function. There still exist point clouds on the robot links.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and helps!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188077/moveit-self-filtering/) by [Loewy](https://answers.ros.org/users/12926/loewy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As explained [here](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/3D_Sensors), you must provide your sensor configuration. The relevant parameters for self-filtering are padding_offset and padding_scale.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0